# Reacts generate two input feilds dynamically instead of one

Tags: reactjs

So this is my app which i have created in react and store data in firestore, i have a form in which ingredients is an array, i can dynamically add the input feilds and when i submit the form it gets submiited and the data gets stored in firebase. My problem is when i click the add feild button instead of one feild  two feilds are simultaneously created and i am unable to understand how to do that so if anyone can explain what to do thanks .

code :

```
function App() {
const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([])
const [form, setForm] = useState({
ingredients: [],
})
const [popupActive, setPopupActive] = useState(false)

const recipesCollectionRef = collection(db, "recipes")

useEffect(() => {
onSnapshot(recipesCollectionRef, snapshot => {
  setRecipes(snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
    return {
      id: doc.id,
      viewing: false,
      ...doc.data()
    }
  }))
 })
}, [])

const handleView = id => {
const recipesClone = [...recipes]

recipesClone.forEach(recipe => {
  if (recipe.id === id) {
    recipe.viewing = !recipe.viewing
  } else {
    recipe.viewing = false
  }
})

setRecipes(recipesClone)
}

 const handleSubmit = e => {
 e.preventDefault()

if (
  !form.ingredients ||
) {
  alert("Please fill out all fields")
  return
}

addDoc(recipesCollectionRef, form)

setForm({
  ingredients: [],
})
setPopupActive(false)
}

const handleIngredient = (e, i) => {
const ingredientsClone = [...form.ingredients]

ingredientsClone[i] = e.target.value

setForm({
  ...form,
  ingredients: ingredientsClone
})
}

const handleIngredientCount = () => {
setForm({
  ...form,
  ingredients: [...form.ingredients, ""]
 })

   { recipe.viewing && <div>
          <h4>Ingredients</h4>
          <ul>
            { recipe.ingredients.map((ingredient, i) => (
              <li key={i}>{ ingredient }</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
```

Comment: Please do elaborate your question. I am not able to find any `onClick` or any form elements in the code.

Comment: my app is a clone of this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zr0i1-bCFHI, please see the first minute of the video where he shows the demo you can see when he adds ingredients he gets one input feild i instead want two. To put it simply in firestore i want an array map

Comment: Yeah I saw, It is explaining only the business logic. I understand that. Just share the logic which you have written which appends the form.

Comment: This one, https://github.com/TylerPottsDev/yt-reactjs-firebase-recipe-app/blob/master/src/App.js

Comment: As far as, I have seen. Everything is working fine in your github code. I saw add ingredient and add step buttons. When I click on those buttons. Only one field is created. Where exactly is the issue ?

Comment: yes, when i press add ingredient i want two input feilds created simultaneously instead of one

Comment: Then you just need to do this => `  const handleIngredientCount = () => {
    setForm({
      ...form,
      ingredients: [...form.ingredients, "", ""],
    })
  }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I have understood. Just do like below,

```
  const handleIngredientCount = () => {
    setForm({
      ...form,
      ingredients: [...form.ingredients, "", ""],
    })
  }
```

You will be created with two input fields simultaneously instead of one when you click the `add ingredient` button.

Comment: it didn't work, i was mistaken, when i do this no change occurs

Comment: Okay. Is it fixed right now ??

Comment: no, still looking actually i had a lasik surgey and i have to returned to laptop after 2 weeks

Comment: It is working properly. I have replicated it in the github repo you have provided. What you need is you need to add  2 fields while pressing `add ingredients` button right ?

Comment: i tried it a new project and it worked, maybe the older version had some bug. Thanks a lot.

Comment: hi sujeet, if possible please take a look at this question, it is related to this one, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73257631/reactjs-firebase-convert-string-to-map